# Issue libperfservice hotplug/cmd couldn't be open

Tags: android, stream, android-camera, inputstream

I'm new on eclipse and android and I want for my first app do a wifi connection between the smartphone and an ip camera, unfortunately my app crash if when I want to see the stream of the camera.

My logcat said that:

```
03-06 18:11:26.879: E/(680): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'<br/>
03-06 18:11:26.879: E/(680): error : 2, No such file or directory
```

---

[Edit k3b 2017-08-09]

I have the same issue on my andriod-4.4 my logcat contain this

```
08-09 20:38:40.436 1883-2035/? I/libPerfService: 1: set: 1
     [ 08-09 20:38:40.436  1883:0x7f3 E/         ]
     Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
     [ 08-09 20:38:40.436  1883:0x7f3 E/         ]
     error : 2, No such file or directory
```

googleing "libPerfService" for found [androidStudio log doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353403/)

```
11-02 02:29:48.792 1014-1231/? I/libPerfService: 1: set freq: 1950000
11-02 02:29:48.792 1014-1231/? I/libPerfService: 1: set: 4
```

found https://census.tsyrklevich.net/file_permissions//system/lib/libperfservice.so with no description

Does anybody know where `libPerfService` comes from? is this a maleware waiting for command? I have not found any defintion for it.